# Finding fingertip efficient method

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on detecting the fingertip after hand segmentation.

The research paper I am working on is [HandyAR](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~holl/pubs/Lee-2007-ISWC.pdf).

Now the paper explains a method based on curvature based detection and fitting an ellipse to detect fingertips.

[image]

One other way I found on web is using the [convex hull](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/782602/Beginners-guide-to-understand-Fingertips-counting).

Which of the following ways is more accurate and reliable?
Given that this complete process has to be real time , which of the following two ways should be better?

Comment: 1) "better" has no meaning as such. 2) Only a guy who has practiced both methods can answer. There's probably a single guy on Earth who did: you.

Comment: @YvesDaoust 1) the meaning of better is that which one is more robust. 2) I didn't know that I am the first person to do this. I asked this because both of these ways have been known for quite long and somebody must have tried them. Thanks for the reply.(I didn't expect this to be downvoted).

Comment: IMO, in some extreme configurations the convex hull approach migh miss a finger. And it will not stand occlusion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried and tested both the methods and I observed that the eclipse method works better than convex hull method for the cases when the palm is not spread out. Thanks